# Evento keypress en jquery

Tags: jquery

Buenas, estoy probando este codigo para permitir que un textbox ingrese solo numeros con Jquery. Cuando lo prueba en Chrome funciona perfecto, pero el problema surge cuando lo pruebo desde Firefox ya que me inhabilita la tecla borrar, no puedo borrar lo que escribo. Una ayuda por favor.

Código jquery que estoy utilizando:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#input').keypress(function(e){
            if(e.charCode < 48 || e.charCode > 57){
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay páginas que bloquean el ingreso de caracteres, copiar o pegar cadenas, etc. En mi opinión esto es pésimo diseño de interfaz de usuario y es mucho mejor validar el ingreso de información y mostrar un mensaje si no es correcto.
Tambien existen plugins para obtener solo campos numericos.  Pero bueno, esto funciona:

```
$(function(){
        $('#input').keypress(function(e){
            console.log(e.charCode);
            if ((e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57) || (e.charCode == 0)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```